# Custom Column - is it Forwardable?

Tags: outlook

I've added an editable Custom Column in Microsoft Outlook (see steps below) that is a Text field where Sensitive Data will be added (for example, a Social Security Number or ID field).  We only want this data accessible within the Mailbox where the Custom Column was added.  My question is, will this data be forwarded when a message from this Mailbox is Replied to or Forwarded?

Adding an editable Custom Column: Right-Click on the Outlook Columns and choose View Settings:
(Settings > Advanced View Settings > Columns > Add Column).
(Settings > Advanced View Settings > Other > check the Allow in-cell editing checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all custom fields and their values will be present on the forwarded item. You would need a macro or add-in to remove them when creating forwarded items.